# scraping ng-repeat <select> elements

Tags: angularjs, ruby, nokogiri

I'm scraping a bunch of locations from a `<select>` element with its respective options. Being naïve, I thought I would scrape all the `<option>` elements with `doc.css('option')` this returned `"Select your region{{r.Name}}{{s.Name}}"`. Which I did some research on and realised it was AngularJS loop.

Is there a way to return some sort of plain list of all the locations in the developer console (using AngularJS)? Or is there some way to scrape all the options that I'm unaware of?

Sample of the html:

```
<option value="" selected="">Select your region</option>
<!-- ngRepeat: r in regions -->
<option ng-repeat="r in regions" value="Auckland" class="ng-binding ng-6cope">Auckland</option>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show a sample of the HTML.

Comment: I'm confused what you actually need. Are you need to know the elements of regions?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need a specific question but yours is very general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done with Nokogiri, because it does not render JavaScript, however, if these options are taken from some kind of API you can call it.

Try to investigate what this page does in your browser development tools, or maybe it's stored somwhere in a `script` tag on the page. I think the best option for you will be to just use Selenium and headless Chrome.

Comment: I friend found it using $ curl.

Comment: Don't use the browser's development tools. Too often browser's munge the HTML prior to displaying it because fo JavaScript, resulting in confusion. Instead, use `curl` or `wget` to retrieve the HTML directly, and view it in an editor.